# Why does $\{\phi,(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)\}$ not semantically entail $\psi$ if $\phi$ has a free variable and $\psi$ doesn't?

Tags: logic

Right off the bat, I want to make clear that my logic lecturer has adopted a rather non-standard form of the predicate calculus in which structures can be empty.  Normally, structures are required to be non-empty in order to prevent this sort of thing from coming up, but it is in fact possible to allow empty structures if you adjust the *modus ponens* rule a bit.

I'm going to quote the following bit from my lecture notes and then explain what I don't understand about it ($\phi$ and $\psi$ refer to formulae throughout):

> We don't always have $\{\phi,(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)\}\models\psi$: if $\phi$ has a free variable and $\psi$ doesn't, then $\phi$ and $(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)$ are always valid in the empty structure, even if $\psi$ is $\bot$.

Here's what I don't understand: since $\phi$ has a free variable, neither $\phi$ nor $(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)$ is a sentence.  Therefore, to make any sense of the statement $\{\phi,(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)\}\models\psi$ we have to add constants to the language and substitute them for the free variables occuring in $\phi$ and $(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)$.  But if the language contains constants then we cannot use the empty set as a structure.  This seems to invalidate the above quotation.  **How am I wrong?**

**About $\Rightarrow$:**

I am used to using $\Rightarrow$ as a symbol with the following special properties:

- If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formulae then $(\phi\Rightarrow\psi$) is a formula (Note - here, $\Rightarrow$ is just a symbol).
- Let $A$ be a structure - i.e., a set $A$ equipped with a function $\omega_A:A^{\alpha(\omega)}\to A$ for each operation symbol $\omega$ and a function $\pi_A:A^{\alpha(\pi)}\to\{0,1\}$ for each predicate symbol $\pi$, the $n$-ary interpretation of the formula $(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)$ in $A$ is the function $(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)_A^{(n)}:A^n\to\{0,1\}$ which, given some element $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ of $A^n$, takes the value $0$ if and only if $\phi_A^{(n)}(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=1$ and $\psi_A^{(n)}(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=0$.

You might be more used to using the symbol $\to$ in this way.  If this is the case, then you have my apologies.

**Definition of $\models$:**

Given a formula $\phi$ and a structure $A$, we say that $\phi$ is *satisfied* in $A$ if the $n$-ary interpretation $\phi_A^{(n)}:A^n\to\{0,1\}$ of $\phi$ in $A$ is the constant function with value $1$.  Given a set $T$ of *sentences* - formulae with no free variables - we define a *model* of $T$ to be a structure $A$ such that every member of $T$ is satisfied in $A$.  If $\phi$ is a formula with no free variables, we say $T$ *semantically entails* $\phi$ and write $T\models\phi$ if $\phi$ is satisfied in every model of $T$.

If $\phi$ or some member of $T$ has a free variable, then we say $T\models\phi$ if $T'\models\phi'$, where $T'$ and $\phi'$ are formed from $T$ and $\phi$ by adding new variables to the language and substituting them in for the free variables in question.  It was this that provoked my confusion: $\{\phi,(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)\}$ has free variables, so we must add constants to the language to make sense of $\{\phi,(\phi\Rightarrow\psi)\}\models\psi$.  But if the language has constants, then the structure must be non-empty!

(Given the disparity between my lecturer's treatment of the subject and that of others, I can only assume that there is a parallel disparity between the vocabulary I have used and that you might be used to - I don't myself know any other words for *formula*, *structure* and so on, but if there's a term you don't recognize, I'll do my best to explain what it means, and maybe then you'll recognize what it is that I'm talking about.)

Comment: It is usually common to denote by $\phi\Rightarrow\psi$ logical implication, that is "for every structure and assignment in which $\phi$ is true we have that $\psi$ is true", while material implication is denoted by $\phi\to\psi$. The latter is a sentence *in* predicate calculus while the former is a sentence *about* predicate calculus sentences. Seeing how things are non-standard, I thought I should point that out to clarify what does $\Rightarrow$ mean in your question.

Comment: Most of your quote from the lecture notes seems to make sense if we assume the convention that a non-closed formula $\phi$ is true in a structure iff its universal closure is. Under this convention _every_ formula with free variables would count as valid in the empty structure. What **doesn't** make sense is the final "... even is $\phi$ is $\bot$, because $\bot$ does not have a free variable. Probably that is a typo for "... even if $\psi$ is $\bot$".

Comment: Thanks - yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Could you edit the question to rephrase and emphasize what exactly you're asking? Also, could you give the definition of $\models$ from your instructor's notes? You have defined a satisfaction function that takes a variable assignment but have not defined what $M \models \phi$ means.

Comment: As an aside, if $x = x$ is valid but $(\exists x)[x = x]$ is not, then more has to be changed in the deductive system than just modus ponens.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: thank you for adding those definitions to the question. I don't see how they match up, either. But given the way that a "structure" is defined there, I am curious how the truth value for a formula $t = s$ is obtained, given that if $A$ is empty then it seems like the "interpretation" of a constant symbol is the empty function.

Comment: (Are you at Cambridge by any chance?)

Comment: @Clive Yes ;) - however did you guess?

Comment: @Donkey_2009: I can smell a PTJ-ism from a mile off!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need constants: the structure could have a predicate $P$ with arity 1. Then we have $\{P(x), (P(x)\rightarrow\bot)\} \not\models \bot$ since in the (unique) model $A$ such that $P_A: \emptyset \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, $P(x)$ and $(P(x)\rightarrow\bot)$ are satisfied: there is a unique function from $\emptyset$ to $\{0,1\}$, so their interpretations are equal to the constant function 1.

The reason is that, as Henning pointed out, your definition of $\models$ adds universal quantifiers, so this simply says that $\forall x\ P(x)$ and $\forall x\ (P(x)\rightarrow\bot)$ are trivially true in the empty structure. And because of the quantifiers, you can't apply the modus ponens to derive a contradiction from that.