# How do I read a ⊢ ab in mathematical logic?

Tags: logic

I'm beginning to read the interesting *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, by *Detlovs* and *Podnieks*, but I'm having some troubles with a few simple concepts.

In an early paragraph, the following theory is described:

> Our second example of a formal theory is only a bit more serious. It was
>       proposed by Paul Lorenzen, so let us call this theory L. Propositions of L are
>       all the possible "words" made of letters a, b, for example: a, b, aa, aba, baab.
>       Thus, the set of all these "words" is the language of L. The only axiom of L is
>       the word a, and L has two rules of inference: X |- Xb, and X |- aXa. This
>       means that (in L) from a proposition X we can infer immediately the
>       propositions Xb and aXa. For example, the proposition aababb is a theorem of
>       L:
>       a |- ab |- aaba |- aabab |- aababb
>       rule1 rule2   rule1    rule1
>       This fact is expressed usually as L |- aababb ( "L proves aababb", |- being a
>       "fallen T").

How do I read **a ⊢ ab**? Surely not "a proves ab", I suppose.

Comment: Although not a duplicate question, I believe some of the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/280384/23353) are that for which you're looking.

Comment: From $a$ one can deduce $ab$.

Comment: $X \vdash \varphi$ means that $\varphi$ is *derivable* from the set $X$ . If we are working in logic (propositional or other), this is exactly : the formula $\varphi$ is *provable* from the set of *axioms* or *assumptions* $X$, by way of the *inference rules* of the system. But we can use this symbol in a more general context : a *formal system*. In this case, we say that the *expression* $\varphi$ is *producible* (or again : *derivable*) from the set of expressions $X$, according to the *transformation rules* of the system.

Comment: I'm glad Mauro mentioned the general context. Here, of course, we're dealing with propositions (things that are true or false), so the usual readings of the \vdash all work. In the general context of expressions that aren't necessarily statements, deducibility and provability wouldn't have made much sense, so we'd have to go with producibility/rewritability.

Comment: @Mauro Would you please convert your comment to an answer? It's definitely answer-worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X \vdash \phi$ means that $\phi$ is derivable from the set [of expressions] $X$.

If we are working in logic (propositional or other), this is exactly :

> the formula $\phi$ is *provable* from the set of axioms or assumptions $X$, by way of the inference rules of the system.

But we can use this symbol in a more general context, like that of a [formal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system).

In this case, we say that :

> the expression $\phi$ is *producible* (or again : derivable) from the set of expressions $X$, according to the transformation rules of the system.