# Difference between ⊢ as connective versus in front

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is the meaning of  ⊢ in the context of  ⊢(P->Q) versus in the context of (P   ⊢ Q)

Comment: $\vdash$ is not a connective. It means taht the formula $(P \to Q)$ is *derivable* in the propositional calculus.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't see an answer to this *specific* question there. Did I miss something?

Comment: Duplicate of [Notation Question: What does ⊢ mean in logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280384/notation-question-what-does-vdash-mean-in-logic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notation Question: What does $\vdash$ mean in logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280384/notation-question-what-does-vdash-mean-in-logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turnstile $\vdash$ means that what is on the right is provable (in some proof system) from what is on the left. So $\vdash P\rightarrow Q$ means that the conditional proposition $P\rightarrow Q$ is provable from nothing, i.e. is a tautology. On the other hand, $P\vdash Q$ means that $Q$ is provable given $P$ as a premise.

Comment: Thanks i love you

Comment: @PabloH then accept the answer.

Comment: @GrahamKemp ok.